# Distributing application WebWorks

Tags: installation, distribution, blackberry-webworks

I have created my application bb webworks. The compile with bbwp and generated the files and folders OTAInstall StandardInstall.

Now what are the options to distribute or install the application?

In meeting this link https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/wwpublishing/distributingyourapp1866990_11.html options but only mentioned. As you run each?

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways that you can load the application on to the device.  You can javaload the cod file from the standardinstall folder or you can install the files from the OTAInstall over the air using a webserver.

Thanks

Naveen M